# How to bold cells containing ** and remove all * in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

How to bold cells containing ** (, and remove all *) in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. It goes throu all the cells in the active sheet:

```
Sub checkStars()
Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:" & Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address)
    If InStr(Cell.Value2, "**") > 0 Then
        Cell.Font.Bold = True
        Cell.Value2 = Replace(Cell.Value2, "**", "")
    End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```